# How can I send input to multiple terminal windows (not tabs)?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

I use gnome-terminal (Ubuntu 10.10).  I like it, though I'd be willing to switch to another for this feature.

Can anyone tell me how I can broadcast keystrokes to multiple *windows*?  The closest thing I've found is the "Terminator" program, which allows for broadcasting to multiple *tabs*, but not to multiple windows.  Apparently a similar feature was removed from v3 of Konsole when it went to v4 (no idea why).  There are also similar capabilities in screen, but not between windows, as far as I can tell.

I've spent a number of hours looking, but no joy.

I'd also be willing for a general solution (input to multiple windows of any kind) that I could adapt for use with terminal windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely superuser. Otherwise, check the [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/). Had no chance to play with it myself, but if it really what it claims to be, then it might to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with a software called [keyboardcast](https://launchpad.net/keyboardcast): `apt-get install keyboardcast`

For the source: http://web.archive.org/web/20100130104001/http://desrt.mcmaster.ca/code/keyboardcast/